# ngOnChanges swapping data between tabs

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two tabs like this in one parent component called as "FoodComponent":

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs [color]='"accent"'>
<mat-tab label="pizza">
<dc-pizza [pizzaContent]="pizzaContent" ></dc-pizza>
</mat-tab>

<mat-tab label="burger">
<dc-burger [burgerContent]="burgerContent"></dc-burger>
</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**Code for PizzaComponent :**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'dc-pizza',
   templateUrl: './dc-pizza.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./dc-pizza.component.scss']
})

export class PizzaComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {    
    @Input() pizzaContent: any;    
    ngOnChanges() {
       this.myfood= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.pizzaContent));
    }
}
```

**Code for BurgerComponent :**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dc-burger',
    templateUrl: './dc-burger.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dc-burger.component.scss']
})

export class BurgerComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() burgerContent: any;
    ngOnChanges() {
        this.myfood= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.burgerContent));
    }
}
```

here now what is happening is whenever i open tab, both these ngOnchanges event get fired and value of burgercontent gets parsed to both myfood.However i want myfood to be filled with corresponding value.

Can i get help in this

Comment: Pls edit your question and add code for `FoodComponent` and add `@Component` decorators to `PizzaComponent` and `BurgerComponent`

Comment: `FoodComponent ` typescript part is missing

Comment: Can you please prepare a [mcve] ?